# Understanding the physical meaning of a plot of a Random Forest model

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, random-forest, unsupervised-learning

When experimenting with Random Forest, I plot the Random Forest model as follows. How should I understand the generated figure? What does each line correspond to, and how to extract the corresponding information and mark it on the plot?

```
library(randomForest)
library(inTrees)
ind<-sample(2,nrow(iris),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))
trainData<-iris[ind==1,]
testData<-iris[ind==2,]
iris_rf <- randomForest(Species~.,data=trainData,ntree=100,proximity=TRUE)
plot(iris_rf)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each curve shows you the classification error rate versus the number of trees in the forest for a given class. The black curve is just the average error rate over all classes. To find out which class each non-black curve represents, a quick and dirty tip consists in comparing the stabilized error rate (given by the plot) to the class error values of the confusion matrix (returned by a call to your randomForest object).

PS1: Annotating plots is not related to statistics and therefore should be asked on Stack Overflow rather than Cross Validated.

PS2: remember to use [`set.seed()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605271/reasons-for-using-the-set-seed-function) to make your example fully reproducible when it involves some degree of randomness (in your case with `sample()`).